# Как сохранить вычисления в UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel

В TextField все получается сохранить. Подскажите способ с лейблом.

```
let userDef = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        oneTF.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t1")
        twoTF.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t2")
        threeTF.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t3")
        
    }
@IBAction func resultButton() {
        
        guard let oneInt = oneTF.text,
              let twoInt = twoTF.text,
              let one = Double(oneInt),
              let two = Double(twoInt)
        else { return }

        let result = one * two
        labelRezult.text = String(format: "%1.f", result)
        threeTF.text = String(format: "%1.f", result)
        
        userDef.setValue(oneTF.text, forKey: "t1")
        userDef.setValue(twoTF.text, forKey: "t2")
        userDef.setValue(threeTF.text, forKey: "t3")

        
    }
}
```

Comment: не очень понятно где именно проблема возникла, вы ведь уже сохраняете данные в префы, положите туда то что нужно для лэйбла и вытаскивайте при необходимости

Comment: Третий TF добавил чисто попробовать сохранить туда результат вычислений, так как не получилось сохранить данные в лейбле. Через userDefaults с лейблом не выходит, советовали делать сохранение в методе viewDidDisapear, но как там это сделать мне пока не ясно. Вообще идея такая выполнили расчет, сохранили введенные данные в TextFild и Label и чтобы после закрытия открытия приложения все было уже в посчитанном виде.

Comment: Если добавить в код:   threeTF.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t3")
        threeTF.isHidden = true
        labelRezult.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t3") то получается то что задумал, но мне кажется это как то коряво) Тоесть сохраняю полученный результат в третьем TF, делаю его скрытым и с него передаю результат в лейбл при загрузке приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такой как мне кажется не совсем красивый вариант:

```
        threeTF.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t3")
        threeTF.isHidden = true
        labelRezult.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t3")
```

сохраняю полученный результат в третьем TF, делаю его скрытым и с него передаю результат в лейбл при загрузке приложения